# "Lib not defined" - node.js discord bot

Tags: node.js, autocode

i am trying to make a verification code for my node.js autocode discord bot, here is my code:

```
let verifiedRole = `${process.env.Verified}`;

//Assigns role to member after using /verify
await lib.discord.guilds['@0.1.0'].members.roles.update({
  role_id: `${verifiedRole}`,
  user_id: context.params.event.member.user.id,
  guild_id: `${context.params.event.guild_id}`,
});
```

i am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: lib is not defined

ReferenceError: lib is not defined
    at (/functions/events/discord/message/button/interaction.js:5:1)

The JSON output of the error is below.
{
  "error": {
    "type": "RuntimeError",
    "message": "lib is not defined",
    "stack": "ReferenceError: lib is not defined\n    at (/functions/events/discord/message/button/interaction.js:5:1)"
  }
```

can someone please help me???

Comment: The error says it exactly. Lib is not defined. That means you haven’t set lib = something or required or imported it as a module. Can you show all your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is exactly what the error says, you are not defining the variable `lib` anywhere. You need to define it at the top of the file. According to one of Autocode's [examples](https://autocode.com/lib/), it looks something like:

```js
const lib = require("lib")({token: '{{ YOUR IDENTITY TOKEN }}'})`
```

This line is not shown anywhere within the code provided in your question, so I assume this is the issue you are having. Note that `lib` must be defined in every file you are using it in, in order to be able to use it in those files. Just having `lib` in one file doesn't make it accessible as a variable in all of your files.